# ¿Qué palabra o expresión puede ser el equivalente de "swag" en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, coloquialismos

Durante los últimos meses he asistido a algunos eventos de tecnología, específicamente de desarrollo de software y uno muy importante referente a la comunidad de [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). En los 4 eventos a los que he asistido me he encontrado que a la serie de productos promocionales tales como playeras, tazas, recipientes, etcétera lo nombran como "*el swag*".

Al principio me costó trabajo saber a qué se referían pero es algo con lo que te familiarizas muy rápido.

Tenía entendido que el *swag* se refería más a tener cierto estilo, un estilo animado y que denota buen humor (de ahí la frase "tiene el *swag*"), no que se refiriera a una serie de artículos de regalo.

Por esto me surgen principalmente dos preguntas:

- ¿Qué palabra o expresión puede ser el equivalente de *swag* en español haciendo referencia a artículos promocionales?
- ¿*Swag* tiene algún otro uso en español aparte de los que he mencionado?

Comment: I think the origin is the informal English use of swag to denote the items stolen by a thief. By extension it is anything you take away from the event even though you were permitted to, indeed even encouraged to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creo que lo que más se le acerca es lo que recomienda [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=swag): **botín**.

Esta palabra tiene dos entradas en el DLE y en la segunda encuentro la acepción más ajustada:

> [*botín*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5zTsusZ%7C5zTy6cn)
>   Del occit. botin, y este del germ. *bytin 'presa'.
>
> 1. m. Despojo que se concedía a los soldados, como premio de conquista, en el campo o plazas enemigas.
> 2. m. Conjunto de las armas, provisiones y demás efectos de una plaza o de un ejército vencido y de los cuales se apodera el vencedor.
> 3. m. **Beneficio que se obtiene de un robo, atraco o estafa.** U. t. en sent. fig.

Como vemos, ya el DLE hace referencia a que también se usa en sentido figurado. Y, en efecto, creo que es muy pertinente en casos así:

> — Ayer fui a un encuentro de Stack Overflow en español. Había multitud de regalitos: bolígrafos, pegatinas, chapas... ¡Menudo **botín** conseguí!

En tanto en cuanto definimos este tipo de pijaditas/regalitos como una pequeña recompensa por haber participado en algún evento.

Comment: Sería un botín cuando te lo llevas pero *swag* son productos promocionales ¿Lo llamarías botín cuando están en el *stand* de la empresa?

Comment: @blonfu yo creo que sí, no deja de ser una bromita. Recuerdo cuando venías las empresas a la facultad y nos atiborrábamos de bolis, caramelos y similares. No lo llamábamos botín, pero creo que habría sido una descripción bastante precisa.

Comment: Si claro, porque os los llevabais, pero me refiero a cuando todavía no los ha cogido nadie. Imagina que tienes una empresa, vas a una convención o congreso o lo que sea y pones tu mesita con tus regalitos: bolis, tazas, imanes, chapas, etc. ¿Dirías a la gente: aquí está nuestro botín, coge lo que quieras y promociona mi empresa? Me parece un poco raro. En inglés *swag* es botín pero también *Products given away free, typically for promotional purposes.*

Comment: @blonfu ah, ya entiendo. Pues allí me pillas. Coincido contigo en que llamar _botín_ a algo que está allí expuesto. El [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5zTy6cn) hace hincapié en la visión del que obtiene el botín, del beneficiario. ¿Y [recompensa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VTkX8K5)? _Aquello que sirve para recompensar_.

Answer (score 3):

Aparte de la [genial respuesta de Fedorqui ("Botín" / "Regalitos")](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21920/5481) a mi se me ocurre `trofeos` (eso sí, admito que es menos apropiado).

En algunos de los eventos en los que yo he estado había un montón de *stands* de distintas empresas. Mis compañeros de trabajo y yo nos turnábamos en nuestro propio *stand*, y en los descansos dábamos un paseo a ver qué había en la conferencia o feria. A veces nos referíamos a esos vagabundeos como "expediciones de caza", ya que íbamos a conseguir algo que habíamos visto que otro compañero había conseguido en un cierto *stand* o nuevos y mejores artículos.

Así que no eran "trofeos" en el sentido de que reconocieran algún logro o que fueran algo que mereciese la pena exhibir o atesorar, pero sí eran el resultado satisfactorio de un esfuerzo por conseguir un determinado elemento.